# How do I avoid NullPointerExceptions in lambda comparators?

Tags: java, lambda, nullpointerexception, java-8, comparison

I want to compare two given objects which might be null at runtime. In my example:

```
@Test
public void shouldCompareAgents() {

    Agent a1 = new Agent();
    a1.setId("4711");
    a1.setType(null);

    Agent a2 = new Agent();
    a2.setId(a1.getId());
    a2.setType(a1.getType());

    assertEquals("Agent.getId", 0,
            Comparator.comparing(Agent::getId).compare(a1, a2));

    assertEquals("Agent.getType", 0,
            Comparator.comparing(Agent::getType).compare(a1, a2));
}
```

The assertion by id works fine, by type does not as `a1.getType()` is null. Is there a way to avoid this? I tried `Comparator.nullsLast(...)`, but that makes no sense as I am not sorting elements here.

I have lots of assertions to do, so I'd prefer **"a one-liner"**. I am new to lambda expressions.

Comment: Why you dont want to use `equals` method?

Comment: I am not able to change _Agent_'s implementation and there is no hashCode/equals.

Comment: What is wrong with `nullsLast`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you just want to use this in a JUnit test, why don't you just pass the objects you want to compare directly to the `assertEquals` method?

```
assertEquals("Agent.getId", a1.getId(), a2.getId());
```

This also helps JUnit to generate a useful error message when the test fails.

If you want to do this in production code, you can use `Objects.equals`:

```
if (Objects.equals(a1.getId(), a2.getId())) { ... }
```

which is present since Java 7.

Answer (score 10):

Something like this:

```
Comparator.comparing(Agent::getType, 
    Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
```

Since you need this to be used in more places, you can extract it as :

```
    private static <R, T extends Comparable<T>> boolean areEqual(R left, R right, Function<R, T> function) {
         return Comparator.comparing(
                 function, 
                 Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())) 
                           .compare(left, right) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Objects.equals`:

```
assertEquals("Agent.getId", true,
    Objects.equals(a1.getID(),a2.getID());

assertEquals("Agent.getType", true,
    Objects.equals(a1.getType(),a2.getType());
```

`Objects.equals` handles `null`s for you.